# Android, Gradle lock file issue

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle, mobile, background

#### Android Gradle Lock File Exception

- I am working an Android project and i am using Kotlin for development , İ did some changes and closed the project and other day when i come and open the Project again , i got issue like this

```kotlin
Could not create parent directory for lock file C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19\wrapper\dists\gradle-7.4-bin\c0gwcg53nkjbqw7r0h0umtfvt\gradle-7.4-bin.zip.lck
```

- I have searched lot of site and i found nothing ,
- There was a same question in the Stack Overflow but answers doesn’t work so i create again for,
- If you have time and could give me some solution or ideas , i will so glad , thank your time

Comment: Something is wrong with your overall [Windows] set-up. Gradle should never try to write to the JDK directory. Uninstall the JDK, delete the folder `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19`, reinstall JDK and make sure to not run gradle with admin permissions.

Comment: i deleted and downloaded but issue is still here , i don't get the gradle admin permission , how can i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Enter this menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1wuQv.png)

[then in the SDK Location menu as shown in the screenshot
you press the place where there is a red line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OeZgF.png)

[When you enter this menu, select the location where all versions of Gradle are stored, then in the "Use Gradle From" field, select what is in the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/olDvG.png)

Answer (score 1):

I figured out ,

> the solution is run as administrator ,When you do it problem goes away

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).